# Dart: How can I download e-mails from a POP server?

Tags: email, dart

I'm developing an application that will handle e-mails from a POP server. It will verify if an incoming e-mail satisfies some rules, and if it does the content of the e-mail will be stored on a database.

As I was looking for something that could be reused, I thought that I could find something on pub.dartlang.org, but there isn't (at least nothing with this description).

So I would like to know if there's any way to download e-mails from a POP server on Dart.

Thanks!

Comment: Asking for software/libraries is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: @MarcB done. Now, maybe, you could help?

Comment: Now it just shows 0 effort.

Comment: @takendarkk and Marc B, both of you are right. I forgot to say in the question that I searched a lot for a solution before coming to SO and I was so focused on finding something ready that I've asked the wrong question. And for the lack of information, it's because I really didn't find anything and didn't have any code done, since I'm still planning on what path I will follow to develop the application. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to re-examine whatever interface they provide.

AFAIK, POP3 doesn't support push, so "POP Push" isn't actually a thing, so they're either not providing a standards-compliant POP or there is some other push interface they've developed.

You can poll POP using any number of libraries or just open a socket, it's not a complicated protocol.

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt

Comment: You're right. There are a lot of people complaining about their services. There are no manuals to help us, so most people decide to download information via e-mail. As I didn't find any libraries "ready to go", I think I'm going to develop something simple to communicate with their server. Thanks for the help!